# how to get mysql values in a single cell one by one in php.?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have table A which contains many employee id. Table B containing fractional employee id. For example, in table A employee id is 40123312 whereas in table B column A 401, column B 233 and column C 12. the question how to get employee id data from table A one by one to be split in table B?.
Data is taken from mysql and the data will be uploaded back to mysql. the table is in mysql and i use CI.

Comment: Are all values in table A 8 digits long?

Comment: No, the values sometimes have 7 digits.

Answer (score 0):

whot about getting Values from B table STORE it in array  COL1 . COL2 . COL3 ... and then connect again to mysqli in FOR loop and check if Array[$i] = 'COL_TABLE_A' ?

Answer (score 0):

You need `foreign keys` on B table to A primary_key to use this query and get your result!

(A field of B table that saves B

`SELECT * FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON B.A_ID = A.ID`